# Parsing key=value pairs in Java with valueless keys enabled

Tags: java, regex

What is the RegExp for parsing key-value pairs from a String that is in the following format:

```
A=B,C,D=E,G=12
```

My first approach was splitting by commas and then processing the result one by one and just wondered if this is possible to do more elegantly using regexp.

Comment: What is _your_ approach?

Comment: I wouldn't use a regex to parse the whole thing, I would separate by `,` first and parse the individual key/values. Note: you might have `A== hello = world =,B=1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Tokenize / explode with comma.
2. Then explode the fragments on '='

Regex not needed.

Answer (score 1):

i think you could do something like this

```
 String sw= "A=B,C,D=E,G=12";
    String[] sArr = sw.split(",");
    for(int i=0; i<sArr.length; i++) {
        String[] arr = sArr[i].split("=");
        if(arr.length>1) {
        for(int j=0; j<arr.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(arr[j]);
        }
        }
    }
```